# How do I create a new data.frame with the same column names and types as an existing data.frame?

Tags: r

I have an existing data.frame that I want to clone, but without the values therein.  ie. I want the new frame to have the same column names and types as the existing one.   The original frame can be of the order of GB, so copying and removing the data doesn't seem like the right way to do it, and iterating over the existing columns to add them to the new frame doesn't seem like a very 'R' way of doing things.

Comment: Do you also want as many *rows* as the original (with NA values)? Or do you want zero rows?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want zero rows, reference the zero-th row:

```
iris[0,]
[1] Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
sapply(iris[0,],class) # still has correct column classes
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
   "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

If you want NA data, reference outside the row domain of the original data:

```
iris[nrow(iris)+1:3,]
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
NA             NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
NA.1           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
NA.2           NA          NA           NA          NA    <NA>
```

Comment: Perfect - your first answer was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!